# Getting a numpy array view with integer or boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy

`numpy` arrays can be partially assigned using integer or boolean indices like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5)
x[[2,4]]=0
x
## array([0., 0., 1., 0., 1.])
x[[True]*2+[False]*3]=2
x
## array([2., 2., 1., 0., 1.])
```

However, even though `x[[2,4]]` is in lvalue in this context, the lvalue cannot be assigned to another variable, because in this case the assignment is done by `__setitem__`, whereas `__getitem__`, when passed an integer or boolean list, creates a copy:

```
x = np.arange(5)
y = x[[2,4]]
y[:] = 1
x
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Question: is there any simple/clean way to get a writeable array view based on an integer-indexed or boolean-indexed index subset?  By "simple/clean" I mean that I want to avoid writing a new class, or keeping track of the sub-indices myself.  Basically I'm looking for some `numpy` function or trick that I haven't been able to google.

The point of this question is to be able to do this recursively, to be able to create functions that assign to pieces of an array by just passing views of the array around, rather than passing indices as well as the base array.

Comment: Basically the amount of information the you want to pass is more than what the `view` model can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice explanation to your question [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html):

> You can create views by selecting a slice of the original array, or also by changing the dtype (or a combination of both). The rule of thumb for creating a slice view is that the viewed elements can be addressed with offsets, strides, and counts in the original array.
>   (...)
>
> The reason why a fancy indexing is not returning a view is that, in general, it cannot be expressed as a slice (in the sense stated above of being able to be addressed with offsets, strides, and counts).
>
> For example, fancy indexing for could have been expressed by , but it is not possible to do the same for by means of a slice. So, this is why an object with a copy of the original data is returned instead.

So as a general rule, **no**, you can't.

In my opinion the most "numpy" way of working with views is by working with masks, and keeping track of these instead of assigning the views to a new variable. I'd simply do:

```
m = [2, 4]
x[m] = some_function(x[m]) # whatever you need to do
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it looks like there's no way to do what I want naturally.  The problem with `f(x[m])` is that it copies `x[m]`, which in recursive functions can lead to a lot of copying, particularly if `x` is 2d, in which case copying `x[m]` is a lot more expensive than copying just `m`.  Writing the function as `f(x,m)` avoids the copying, but is less clean.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: is there any simple/clean way to get a writeable array view based on an integer-indexed or boolean-indexed index subset?

**No.**

NumPy arrays (and views) are required to have constant strides (i.e., the distance between elements in memory has to be constant). If your indexing operation would create an object that violates this limitation, you are out of luck.

See e.g. [here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/How-to-concatenate-two-arrays-without-duplicating-memory-td24121.html) for a discussion of a related problem:

> You cannot in the numpy memory model. The numpy memory model defines an
>   array as something that has regular strides to jump from an element to
>   the next one.